# Jquery: How to set delay and slide up on newly created element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set the newly created element to slide up after a few seconds.

```
$("div[data-error='true']").delay(5000).slideUp(500, function () {
    $("#error-alert").remove();
});
$("div[data-success='true']").delay(5000).slideUp(500, function () {
    $("#success-alert").remove();
});
```

For instance these are the elements that will be added up dynamically:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" id="error-alert1" data-success="true">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
    @ViewBag.Error
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
</div>

<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success-alert1" data-error="true">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Success:</span>
    @ViewBag.Success
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
</div>
```

How to set the dynamically created element to have this slideup, delay, remove event as above described?

Comment: Please also include the code you are using to dynamically create those elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a delay you can use the `setTimeout()` function like

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("div[data-error='true']").slideUp(500, function () {
        $("#error-alert").remove();
    });
}, 5000)
```

I think it should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

`$.delay()` is only advisable when used to delay effects as part of a collection of animation/effects.

You should use JavaScript's native `setTimeout()` instead.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $("div[data-error='true']").slideUp(500, function () {
      $("#error-alert").remove();
  });
  $("div[data-success='true']").slideUp(500, function () {
      $("#success-alert").remove();
  });
}, 3000);
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" id="error-alert1" data-success="true">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
    @ViewBag.Error
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
</div>

<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success-alert1" data-error="true">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Success:</span>
    @ViewBag.Success
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the Error alert in a queue.

```
$("div[data-error='true']").delay(5000).slideUp(500).queue(function () {
   $("#error-alert").remove();
   $(this).dequeue();
});
$("div[data-success='true']").delay(5000).slideUp(500).queue(function () {
   $("#success-alert").remove();
    $(this).dequeue();
});
```

Or the slideUp also in the queue function.